# Why is my web page is automatically scrolling in selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

Am trying to access WebElement properties of a table in a webpage. Doing so is causing the page to automatically scroll down.

For Example, get The WebElement using xpath

```
IWebElement list = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='BOM Detail Data_data_panel']/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/table[1]"));
```

On Trying to access below statement the page is scrolling

```
bool text = list.Displayed;
```

How can i stop scrolling?

Comment: Can you please explain why this is a problem? Is it scrolling the element you're accessing into view?

Comment: yes. My main idea is to aceess a Table first then Cell. so, while iam tring to find element, the page is scrolled iam not able to see the found element

Comment: `string text = list.Displayed;` won't even compile. Please post the real code you are using, including all the steps between locating the element and the line causing the problem.

Comment: edited code, not only displayed property any property of webelement trying to access, facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can stop scrolling in WebDriver. It's how it has been designed. it does the native event rather than javascript events it used to do in Selenium RC.

For example, how would you click in element without scrolling down to that element if it's not in view port.

However, if you don't want to scroll when you try to click some element. I think you should you **javascript** to click on that element.

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').click();");
```